# Issues with SqlException in .NET 7 using MediatR

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, mediatr

I am trying to capture the errors that my stored procedure throws  which in certain cases validates an information and if it returns a `RAISEERROR`, but it does not enter the `SqlException` in the catch.

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CivilStatusSave
    (@CivilStatusId CHAR(1), 
     @CivilStatusName NVARCHAR(15),
     @CreateBy NVARCHAR(60),
     @CreationDate DATETIME,
     @ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(60),
     @ModifiedDate DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CivilStates AS cs 
                   WHERE cs.CivilStatusId = @CivilStatusId)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este codigo', 12, 1);
            RETURN;
        END
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CivilStates AS cs 
                   WHERE UPPER(cs.CivilStatusName) = UPPER(@CivilStatusName))
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este estado civil', 12, 1);
            RETURN;
        END

        INSERT INTO CivilStates (CivilStatusId, CivilStatusName,
                                 CreateBy, CreationDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate)
        OUTPUT inserted.CivilStatusId, inserted.CivilStatusName,
               inserted.CreateBy, inserted.CreationDate,
               inserted.ModifiedBy, inserted.ModifiedDate
        VALUES (@CivilStatusId, @CivilStatusName,
                @CreateBy, @CreationDate, @ModifiedBy, @ModifiedDate);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER INT, @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000), @XACT_STATE INT;

        SELECT 
            @ERRORNUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER(), 
            @MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
            @XACT_STATE = XACT_STATE();

        RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, 16, 1);
    END CATCH
END
```

This is the code for me, where I have the try catch,

```
public async Task<BaseResponse<CivilStatusResponseDto>> Handle(CreateCivilStatusCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    BaseResponse<CivilStatusResponseDto> response = new BaseResponse<CivilStatusResponseDto>();

    try
    {
        CivilStatus civilStatus = await _civilStatusRepository.SaveCivilStatus(_mapper.Map<CivilStatus>(request));

        response.IsSuccess = true;
        response.Data = _mapper.Map<CivilStatusResponseDto>(civilStatus);
        response.Message = GlobalMessages.MESSAGE_SAVE;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Source is not null && ex.Source.Contains("SqlClient"))
        {
            response.IsSuccess = false;
            response.Message = ex.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            response.IsSuccess = false;
            response.Message = GlobalMessages.MESSAGE_EXCEPTION;
            WatchLogger.Log(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

And this is a screenshot of a `SqlException` that has been thrown:

[image]

When I place a breakpoint:

[image]

I tried my best, to access these properties but I can't.

I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Are you catching `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`?

Comment: I tried with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, since the other library does not allow me to import it in order to capture the error

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  But they are different types, and so your catch block must specify the correct one.

Comment: But it is that the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException that is indicated to me is not allowing me to import that library, the system one is, but the one I am telling you about is not and I don't understand why

Comment: Did you add a reference to the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Comment: If david, when adding the nuget package that you tell me about, it already enters the sqlexception, as it should be, put it as an answer to validate it, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Instead of using `RAISERROR...RETURN` just do `THROW...` Remove the `BEGIN CATCH` block it's not doing anything helpful except mucking up the exception flow.

Answer (score 0):

**Your primary issue is that you are catching the wrong type.** You need to catch `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.

Also, your procedure's error handling leaves a lot to be desired:

- Use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`.
- Set `XACT_ABORT` to be `ON` for better error handling. Errors will force immediate termination of the batch or procedure.
- Remove the `BEGIN CATCH` block. It is doing nothing useful, and serves only to mess up the exception flow, and to cause some types of errors to be swallowed or be returned incorrectly.
- Use an actual transaction around the whole thing, to ensure consistency.

  - This therefore requires `UPDLOCK` locking hints on the `SELECT` queries
- Instead of changing to `UPPER` use `COLLATE someCaseInsensitiveCollationHere`. Even better: change the actual collation of the column.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE CivilStatusSave
     @CivilStatusId CHAR(1), 
     @CivilStatusName NVARCHAR(15),
     @CreateBy NVARCHAR(60),
     @CreationDate DATETIME,
     @ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(60),
     @ModifiedDate DATETIME
AS

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM CivilStates AS cs WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE cs.CivilStatusId = @CivilStatusId)
BEGIN
    THROW 50001, 'Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este codigo', 1;
END;
        
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM CivilStates AS cs WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE cs.CivilStatusName = @CivilStatusName COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
BEGIN
    THROW 50002, 'Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este estado civil', 2;
END;

INSERT INTO CivilStates
    (CivilStatusId, CivilStatusName, CreateBy,
     CreationDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate)
OUTPUT inserted.CivilStatusId, inserted.CivilStatusName,
       inserted.CreateBy, inserted.CreationDate,
       inserted.ModifiedBy, inserted.ModifiedDate
VALUES (@CivilStatusId, @CivilStatusName, @CreateBy,
        @CreationDate, @ModifiedBy, @ModifiedDate);

COMMIT;
```

To be honest, you can in theory just rely on unique/primary keys to enforce the conditions, although the error messages are less understandable.